# Disk page size for MySQL and MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, disk-structures

As I know database reads data from disk in some constant page size (even if one byte is needed, whole page will be copied from disk to memory).
What are disk page sizes for MySQL and MySQL Cluster?
Is this value configurable or is fixed and depends on db engine/operating system?

Comment: Not a difficult question to answer from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html).

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB has a default page size of 16K.